# How do I get excel to take scores and rank them for me?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a table or projects. Next to each project name is a score for various criteria as well as a total score.

On another sheet I want excel to pull the project names, associated scores and then auto rank them based on the score. Help!

As an example: I would like it to take this first table and turn it into the second table on a new sheet.

[image]

Comment: In your question you should at least show your existing sheet(s) and the result you would like to get. You can [edit] your question to add this information.

Comment: There is a SORT function in Excel 365: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sort-function-22f63bd0-ccc8-492f-953d-c20e8e44b86c

Comment: For table 2, do a vlookup against your table 1 data to get your total score. Then use the excel Rank function.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to use Power query.

1. Go to Data -> From Table/Range. Select my table has headers. Click OK.
2. Sort the Total column in Descending order.
3. On the Add Column tab, click on Index Column, select From 1. Change the added column name to "Rank" and move it to be the first column.

[image]

[image]

4. Select columns Score1, Score2 and Score 3, then delete them.

[image]

These will be your steps:

[image]

5. Close and save Query editor. This will be the result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Use `LARGE` to get the scores with the appropriate RANK
- Use `INDEX/MATCH` to return the Project Name
- This method does not handle ties

  - If you have Office 365, you can use `FILTER` and `SORT` functions to handle ties.

In the formula below, I assumed Table 1 is a **REAL** table, and used structured references, but you can use regular addressing if you prefer:

```
Ranking Table: Total column
    =LARGE(Table1[Total],G21)

Project Name Column:
    =INDEX(Table1[Project Name],MATCH(I21,Table1[Total],0))
```

[image]